# How to subclass QStandardItemModel to use my own Item type?

Tags: c++, qt, model, subclass

How do I subclass `QStandardItemModel` to use my own Item type (e.g. `MyItem` instead of `QStandardItem`)? I mean I know I have to create a class and inherit `QStandardItemModel` but what next? How do I make it **use `MyItem`** everywhere? And yes, `MyItem` inherits after `QStandardItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is impossible. You can subclass QAbstractItemModel to implement a model that use your item class.

Also you can use default QStandardItemModel and add your additional object to items using `QStandardItem::setData`. Since it accepts QVariant, you can put any value in it, event QSharedPointer (you need to register appropriate meta type).

Comment: **(1)** Why is it impossible to use `QStandardItemModel` and possible to use `QAbstractItemModel`? And how do I make my model class use `QStandardItem` when using `QAbstractItemModel`? **(2)** How exactly do I use this `setData` (**example, please!**).

Comment: It is impossible because `QStandardItemModel` doesn't provide an option for that, its implementation can't do that.  With `QAbstractItemModel` you can do anything but you will need to implement more things manually. Using `setData` is tricky in this case, I'm not sure it will be really useful.

Comment: Actually `setData` is what finally did the trick. In the end, I didn't have to store any values in items but I tried and it worked, too.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to subclass model, just item class. All you need is this:

```
class YourItem : public QStandardItem
{
// ...
public:
       virtual QStandardItem *clone() const;
};

QStandardItem *YourItem::clone() const
{
    return new YourItem(/*your constructor parameters to copy data if needed*/);
}
```

when installing model:

```
model->setItemPrototype(new MyItem());
ui->listView->setModel(model);
```

Comment: It appears that at least for an editable QComboBox in pyqt 5.12 that it will ignore the models item prototype and just construct a new QStandardItem when you type in the combo box and hit enter/return. One way around this is to handle the rowsInserted signal on the model and replace the item if it has the wrong type.